# How to Export filtered Sharepoint List data into excel in 2007

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I need to export only filtered data into excel from SharePoint List. When i filter and export it gives all data but I need only filtered data.
Is it possible to export only filtered data in SharePoint 2007 List?
And I need to filter on some columns like “Product Type”, Product Category”, “Name” and “Date Range”.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Azad

Answer (score 0):

The OOB Export To Excel exports all items present in a view even though filters may be applied on it from the UI. So, in order to export only the relevant data create a new view with required filters and then export to excel.

Comment: Thanks Nadeem, But there is no fix filter criteria,user can use any value like product type may be Electronic or medicine etc and the filter should be on multiple column. So how can i create multiple view for each condition.

Comment: This is something which may be taught to users that the filters aren't going to work. Perhaps they should filter the data from excel once the file is exported.

Comment: This is the reason why client saying i don't want to export all the data infect they need only filtered data.

Comment: Then brace yourself for custom development. I don't know of any OOB way of doing it.